# Rearrange file content to prepend record 'header' line to each record 'body' line

Tags: text-processing

Anyone have idea how to turn this:

```
FX_AM140_EML AM140
Backend/aa.java
Backend/bb.java
Backend/cc.java
Backend/dd.java
Backend/ee.java

FX_AM172_EML AM172
Backend/aa.java
Backend/bb.java
```

Into this?

```
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/bb.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/cc.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/dd.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/ee.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/bb.java
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like with`awk` can do the work:

```
awk '/^FX/ {a=$0;next} /^Backend/ {print a,$0}' <input file>
```

Here I assume the head line start with `FX` and other start with `Backend`

Answer (score 6):

Another `awk` approach which considers the first line in a group of lines delimited by empty lines as the prefix:

```
awk '
  $0 == ""     {prefix = ""; next}
  prefix == "" {prefix = $0; next}
               {print prefix, $0}'
```

Comment: The above answer can be as  `awk '!NF{getline;f=$0;next}{print f,$0}'`. Is it  correct?

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh, `!NF` is not the same as `$0 == ""` as it also returns true for non-empty blank lines. Your approach wouldn't work correctly if there was an even number of blank lines between groups.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh no, `f` wouldn't be populated for the first block of lines (you'd need to add `NR==1{f=$0}` at the start or handle it otherwise) and `getline` itself comes with some baggage to handle, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Answer (score 3):

A Perl suggestion. The driver for this variant is that groups of lines are separated by a blank line:

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN {$/ = "\n\n"}
    ($p, @a) = split("\n");
    print "$p $_\n" foreach @a;
' datafile
```

It's more readable as several lines but it could be crunched into a single line (I've swapped the `BEGIN` clause for `-00`, which also switches on paragraph mode):

```
perl -00 -ne '($p, @a)=split("\n"); print "$p $_\n" foreach @a' datafile
```

The `awk` equivalent is this (which can also be crunched to a single line by simple concatenation):

```
awk -v RS= '
    {
        split($0, a, "\n");
        p=a[1]; delete a[1];
        for (f in a) {
            print p, a[f]
        }
    }
' datafile
```

Setting the record separator (`RS`) to an empty string switches on paragraph mode ([POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), and search for "*If RS is null*")

Output

```
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/bb.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/cc.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/dd.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/ee.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/bb.java
```

Comment: Nice one Chris. But I get an additional last line as FX_AM172_EML AM172

Comment: @elmo mmm, I don't see why `awk` should create a trailing blank line, but it does. It's fixed now - blank lines are ignored

Comment: You can make the one-liner even shorter with `perl -00 -ne '($p, @a) = split("\n"); print "$p $_\n" for @a;' file`.

Comment: @terdon not intentionally playing golf. Well, not much :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could try awk. Using your sample input as file q763021:

```
$ awk 'NF<1{next}/FX_AM/{a=$0;next}{print a,$0}' q763021 
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/bb.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/cc.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/dd.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/ee.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/bb.java
```

Answer (score 2):

A Perl approach which uses any line that does not contain `/` as the prefix for the others:

```
$ perl -lne 'if(/^(.[^\/]+)$/ || /^$/){ $k=$1; next} print "$k $_"' file
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/bb.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/cc.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/dd.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/ee.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/bb.java
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '/\//{print h, $0; next} {h=$0}' file
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/bb.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/cc.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/dd.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/ee.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/bb.java
```

or if the header lines sometimes have `/`s or the data lines sometimes don't:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $2}' file
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/aa.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = slurp.trim.split("\n\n").map: *.lines; for 0..@a.elems {  \
                    put join " ", @a[$i][0], $_ for @a[$i][1..*] }'  file
```

OR

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = slurp.trim.split("\n\n").map: *.lines;           \
                    for 0..@a.elems { for @a[$i][1..*] -> $tail {    \
                    put join " ", @a[$i][0], $tail }}'  file
```

Above are comparatively verbose answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The code can be used to take a record 'header' and use it as a prefix which gets added to following 'body' lines.

(The `slurp` function reads the file in all-at-once, so may not be appropriate for extremely large files. The `trim` function removes leading and trailing whitespace, so may be omitted for well-behaved logfiles).

Output:

```
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/bb.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/cc.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/dd.java
FX_AM140_EML AM140 Backend/ee.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/aa.java
FX_AM172_EML AM172 Backend/bb.java
```

https://raku.org